# Buscar valores de una lista en un csv por columna Python

Tags: python

Lo que quiero hacer es identificar a que Sitio le falta alguna fecha de la lista llamada fechas. Para ser mas claro dejo un ejemplo con data:

```
fechas = ['1/1/2000','2/1/2000','3/1/2000','4/1/2000', '5/1/2000']

file:

Sitio,Fecha,Importe
a.com,1/1/2000,2
a.com,2/1/2000,3
a.com,3/1/2000,1
a.com,4/1/2000,5
```

En este caso me faltaría la fecha `5/1/2000` entonces quisiera que imprimiera el nombre del sitio `('a.com ej')` y la fecha faltante

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
df.sort_values(by=['Sitio','Fecha'])

fechas = df.drop_duplicates(['Fecha'])
fechas = list(fechas['Fecha'])
```

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta... dices que te falta en ese ejemplo la fecha `5/1/2000`, pero en cambio yo la veo ahi... en la última línea...

Comment: Si disculpa, escribi mal el ejemplo. @JLDiaz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ver si lo entendí correctamente. Supongamos que éste es el contenido del CSV:

```py
contenido = """
Sitio,Fecha,Importe
a.com,1/1/2000,2
a.com,2/1/2000,3
a.com,3/1/2000,1
a.com,4/1/2000,5
b.com,1/1/2000,2
b.com,2/1/2000,3
b.com,3/1/2000,1
b.com,5/1/2000,5
"""
```

En este caso el conjunto de fechas posibles sería `['1/1/2000', '2/1/2000', '3/1/2000', '4/1/2000', '5/1/2000']`, y al sitio `a.com` le falta el `5/1/2000`, mientras que a `b.com` le falta el `4/1/2000`.

Empiezo con un código igual al que proporcionas en la pregunta (pero en vez de leer de un fichero lo leo de la cadena anterior):

```py
import pandas as pd
import io

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(contenido))
df.sort_values(by=['Sitio','Fecha'])

fechas = df.drop_duplicates(['Fecha'])
fechas = list(fechas['Fecha'])
```

El siguiente código detecta qué fecha falta en cada sitio. Es un poco farragoso, pero no se me ocurre forma más sencilla:

```py
grupo = df.groupby("Sitio")
for site, dates in grupo.Fecha.unique().to_dict().items():
    diff = set(fechas) - set(dates)
    if diff:
        print("Al sitio {} le faltan las fechas {}".format(
               site, diff))
```

> Salida:
>
> `Al sitio a.com le faltan las fechas {'5/1/2000'}`
>   `Al sitio b.com le faltan las fechas {'4/1/2000'}`

### Cómo funciona

`pd.groupby("Sitio")` agrupa todas las entradas juntando las que corresponden al mismo sitio. Sobre el grupo resultante hago un `grupo.Fecha.unique()` que me devuelve un dataframe en el que cada fila es un sitio diferente, y en la columna se tiene la lista de fechas (únicas) que aparecen para ese sitio.

Convierto ese dataframe a un diccionario para iterar más fácilmente sobre él, y simplemente voy comparando el conjunto de fechas de cada sitio con el conjunto de fechas "global", haciendo la diferencia de ambos conjuntos y mostrando aquellos que den una diferencia no vacía.

## Actualización

Ante la petición adicional de generar un CSV con el resultado, una opción puede ser la siguiente.

En lugar de ir imprimiendo los sitios a los que les faltan fechas, los vamos guardando en una lista. Cada elemento de la lista será un diccionario con dos claves: "Sitio" y "Faltan_fechas", que contendrán respectivamente el nombre del sitio y una cadena que concatene las fechas faltantes.

Esa estructura es fácil de convertir en DataFrame pandas, y de ahí es trivial volcarla como CSV. Es decir, para acumular los resultados en una lista de diccionarios:

```py
grupo = df.groupby("Sitio")
resultado = []
for site, dates in grupo.Fecha.unique().to_dict().items():
    diff = set(fechas) - set(dates)
    if diff:
        resultado.append(dict(Sitio=site, 
                              Faltan_fechas=",".join(diff)))
```

Para convertirlo a Dataframe:

```py
df_result = pd.DataFrame(resultado, 
                         columns=["Sitio", "Faltan_fechas"]
                        ).sort_values(by="Sitio")
```

Para volcarlo a CSV:

```py
df_result.to_csv("resultado.csv", index=False)
```

En este caso el fichero contendría:

```
Sitio,Faltan_fechas
a.com,5/1/2000
b.com,4/1/2000
```

En caso de que hubiera un sitio al que faltaran varias fechas, por ejemplo `c.com`, se volcaría esto:

```
Sitio,Faltan_fechas
a.com,5/1/2000
b.com,4/1/2000
c.com,"5/1/2000,4/1/2000,2/1/2000"
```

Este CSV solo tiene dos columnas, como ves, pero en la segunda puede haber una cadena separada por comas con varias fechas (que son una sola celda porque va entre comillas)

## Actualización de la actualización

Para generar una salida en la que los sitios aparezcan repetidos tantas veces como fechas falten, esta es una opción:

```py
grupo = df.groupby("Sitio")

resultado = []
for site, dates in grupo.Fecha.unique().to_dict().items():
    diff = set(fechas) - set(dates)
    if diff:
        for fecha in sorted(diff):
            resultado.append(dict(Sitio=site, Faltan_fechas=fecha))
```

La generación del dataframe y del csv queda como antes. Ejemplo de resultado:

```
Sitio,Faltan_Fechas
a.com,5/1/2000
b.com,4/1/2000
c.com,2/1/2000
c.com,4/1/2000
c.com,5/1/2000
```

Comment: Totalmente, eso es lo que buscaba. Muchas gracias

Comment: Me gustaría guardar las respuestas dentro de un csv, sabes como puedo hacerlo??

Comment: @MartinBouhier El problema es cuando a un sitio (por ejemplo `a.com`) le faltan varias fechas. En ese caso ¿qué guardarías en el CSV? ¿Una columna para cada fecha que falte, o una cadena de caracteres en una sola columna con la lista de todas las fechas que faltan?

Comment: Una columna para cada fecha que falte sería lo ideal! pero sino se puede lo que puedas. Gracias

Comment: `a.com,13/02/18
a.com,17/02/18 
a.com,10/02/18
a.com,02/02/18
a.com,01/02/18
a.com,07/02/18` que para cada fecha corresponda el nombre del sitio entonces me quedarían dos columnas con el sitio repetido la cantidad de fechas que falte